# Unexpected behaviour of useReducer hook in React JS

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-reducer, react-18

Can anyone just let me know why I am getting two console prints here?

Here below is my code:

```
import React, {useReducer} from 'react';

const Counter = () => {

    const initialState = { count: 0 }

    const reducer = (state, action) => {
      switch(action.type) {
        case 'INC':
            console.log(state)               <------- It is getting print twice
            return {
                count: state.count++
            }
        case 'DEC':
            console.log(state)
            return {
                count: state.count--
            }
        default:
            
            return {
                count: state.count
            }
    }
}

const [componentState, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

return (
    <>
        {componentState.count}
        <button onClick={() => dispatch({type: 'INC'})}>Increase</button>
        <button onClick={() => dispatch({type: 'DEC'})}>Decrease</button>
    </>
)
}

export default Counter;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

it's due to strict mode, In index.js try to remove react strict mode. you will get only one console,

***Note**: this would be called only once on production*

Comment: If I replace <React.StrictMode> with <React> then page is getting blank and getting few errors in the console.

Comment: dont replace anything simple remove strict mode so  ,root.render(
 
      <App />
    
);